# Load balancer on Ansible Automation Platform

Tags: load-balancing, ansible, automation

Need one help with Load balancers for Ansible Automation Platform.
Actually I ve upgraded from Anisble Tower 1.2 to Ansible Automation platform 2.3.
Now I am not sure which IP's should I expose to Load balancer.
My new configuration is as below:

**In Control Pane Servers:**

1. Control Node #1 (10.0.1.10)
2. Control Node #2 (10.0.1.20)
3. Hybrid Node (10.0.1.30)

**In Exection Pane:**

1. Exection Node #1
2. Execution Node#2

**Existing Tower 1.2 configuration**

1. Tower#1 : 67.0.0.10
2. Tower#2 : 67.0.0.11
3. Tower#3 : 67.0.0.12

In Exiting LB Configuration all the above IPs are exposed along with one friendly IP is assigned and who decides the friendly IP ?

Thank you in advance

Just incase it may help anyone. We need to place the control nodes and hybrid node behind the LB. And LB IP will expose to outside world.

Answer (score 0):

Just incase it may help anyone.
We need to place the control nodes behind the LB. And LB IP will expose to outside world.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but you used the answer button as an additional hint. Your own question was, which node need to be exposed to the LB. Your answer is partly wrong (because for example, use an ingress for that) and it doesnt really explain your solution. Maybe explain, this is a workaround or something like that.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. As I said we need to place control and hybrid node behind LB.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/569973)